# IBM i Access Client Solutions not working with Ubuntu 19.10 and 20.04

Tags: java, 20.04, emulation, ibm

I have used IBMi Access Client Solutions (ACS) with Ubuntu 16.04 for a few years for 5250 (green screen) access etc. without any problems. I recently decided to update to 20.04. I can install the latest ACS (1.1.8.4 build 0160) and start it up to the main panel. I can use the menu option in the main panel to check for updates (none) but when I try to start 5250 emulation or anything else the wait cursor just spins (nothing else happens and I can't kill it with X).

I tried starting it from a terminal window - it does the same and there are no errors in the terminal. I turned logging to FINEST (via Edit->Preferences) but there are no obvious serious failures in any of the logs. The same thing happens with Ubuntu 19.10. In both cases I just installed from the ISO, installed Java (Open JDK 8) then installed ACS. It says I had to install package Dialog which I did. The installation runs fine, and as I said, the main panel opens fine.

I have just tried with Ubuntu 18.04 and that all works there, so it seems that something after 18.04 broke it.

Does anyone have any ideas or experience of this problem?

Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted IBM support and got a good response with a solution, and that is to use the AdoptOpenJDK 11. I tried this and it does indeed work with ACS working as expected.

I then asked why this was so and was told that the default Ubuntu's Java has always been headless. I said that I specifically did not install the headless version but the straight JDK, as I had done with earlier versions of Ubuntu (see above) which worked. Also, I have my own little Spring GUI Java Application and that starts up and runs fine with the Ubuntu JDK 8.

So I still don't understand the difference and why the AdoptOpenJDK works and the standard OpenJDK (now) does not with ACS, but at least ACS is working.